# How to represent the spherical wave by using Fock basis?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

Suppose I have two particles with opposite momentum:
$$
|\psi \rangle_{\mathbf k} = |\mathbf k; -\mathbf k\rangle ,\quad |\mathbf k| = M
$$
I want to represent the spherical symmetric distribution of particles (i.e., to make the summation over all possible momentums) in order to obtain the spherical wave.

How to do that? Does following expression look like the correct one?
 i.e., to get something like
$$
\tag 1 |\psi\rangle = \int d\Omega f(k)|\mathbf k; -\mathbf k\rangle
$$

An edit. For the one-particle state the relation between the state with definite momentum and helicity and the state with definite total angular momentum $j$ and helicity $\lambda$ is
$$
|j, \lambda, |\mathbf k|\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{2j+1}{4\pi}}\int d\Omega_{\mathbf k}D^{j}_{\lambda \lambda{'}}|\mathbf k , \lambda{'}\rangle,
$$
where $D^{j}_{m \lambda{'}}$ is Clebsch-Gordan coefficient and $d\Omega$ is the solid angle element. Intuitively I think that the spherical wave corresponding to $|\mathbf k , -\mathbf k \rangle$ then will be
$$
\tag 1 |0,0, |k|\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi}}\int d\Omega_{\mathbf k}|\mathbf k, -\mathbf k\rangle
$$
Moreover, I think that for zero helicity state combined from non-zero helicity states,
$$
|\mathbf k , \sigma ; -\mathbf k , -\sigma\rangle,
$$
the transformation which generates the spherical wave will be the same as $(1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a spherical wave?

Comment: @oscarafone : suppose the decay of one particle in CM frame into two particles. Corresponding decay is spherically symetric, and hence two particles create the spherical wave.

Comment: @oscarafone : More precisely, I'm looking for the relation of two-particle Fock state (each state of which has probably nonzero helicity) with zero total angular momentum, which denotes the spherical wave.